# $5\sigma$ and population standard deviation

Tags: statistics

Does $5\sigma$ represent a data point that is five standard deviations from the mean?  If so, suppose we come across data that is for some reason $4$ or $5$ standard deviations from the mean. Could this be determined using the $\textit{population standard deviation}$?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Basic_examples

When would it be advised to divide by $\textit{n}$ as opposed to $\textit{n-1}$, and under what conditions could someone use this method to determine the standard deviation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When would it be advised to divide by n  as opposed to n-1 , and under
>   what conditions could someone use this method to determine the
>   standard deviation?

If you have the data of the (whole) population, then you divide the sum of squares by n. The definition of the term "population" is defined/explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_population).

The population could be the member of a community. And the property could be the age. If you have all the data of the ages of the members, than you don´t have to estimate the standard deviation. You just calculate it. n in the denominator.

If you don´t have all the data, then you make a sample of size n. From this sample you can calculate an estimator for the standard deviation. This estimator is unbiased, if you have n-1 in the denominator, instead of n.

The sample values should be drawn independetly and with replacement.

> Does 5σ  represent a data point that is five standard deviations away from
>   the mean.

If you mean  $\overline x+5 \sigma$ or $\overline x-5 \sigma$, then you are correct.

Comment: Calculus:  Thanks for your post and your thoughtful explanation, as well as answering my multiple questions.  Appreciate it!